# Django Model filter with keyword

Tags: django, django-models

I am doing a keyword search.

when user enter a keyword, it could be 'order_num' or 'custom_name',

when I do `filter(Q(order_num=keyword) | Q(custom_name=keyword))`

it raise a Value error.

because the `order_num` is a int, and `custom_name` is a str.

how to make this query with keyword ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `int(keyword)` to convert the search keyword, but since user might input string, you need to distinguish that:

```
try:
    result = Model.objects.filter(Q(order_num=int(keyword)) |
                                  Q(custom_name=keyword))
except ValueError:
    # no point to filter order_num because it's not a number anyway
    result = Model.objects.filter(custom_name=keyword)
```

**Edit:**

Even if there are multiple fields it would be the same:

```
# create an empty Q() object to start with
query = Q()

try:
    int_keyword = int(keyword)
    query |= Q(order_num=int_keyword)
    query |= Q(another_int_field=int_keyword)
except ValueError:
    pass
# the string query would always be executed
query |= Q(custom_name=keyword)
query |= Q(other_field=keyword)

results = Model.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: if i had 3 more field need to filter, then I have to `try a lot`. so, any easier way to do this query?

Comment: I edited my answer. Just wrap all int field queries in `try except` block would be enough. See if that makes sense.